# CSS Position not working when specifying Top / Bottom / Left / Right

Tags: css, position, css-position

Specifying a value greater than, or less than zero for top/bottom/left/right has no effect.

Created an id that specifies `position: absolute`. I can also declare locations but only with zero values i.e. `top: 0` or `right: 0`. Nothing happens though when I specify `right:50`.

I can't work out why. I've stripped nearly everything out of my document.

Here's the CSS:

```
#index-content  {
                position:absolute;
                top:349;
                right:0;
                background-color: fuchsia;
                }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="index-content">The Title</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `px` or another units, like `%`, `em`, `pt` etc when you set numerical values in css.

Answer (score 4):

Use pixels (px) in your values. Top should be top: 349px;

Comment: Thank you very much! I cannot believe I forgot to state the unit. Silly error, thanks for taking the time to say.

Answer (score 1):

Only when you write 0, you don't need to use units.
For numbers any other than 0, you need to define a unit type (i.e. pixels, em, pt, percent, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the body's position as relative or absolute (non-static).